# Display data out of 2 different json-strings with nested ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json, google-sheets, angularjs-ng-repeat

I do have json strings (2 different databases).
As an example:

```
[{
    sport: football, 
    sportid: 1
},{
    sport: tennis,
    sportid: 2
},{
    sport: golf,
    sportid: 3
},{
    sport: swimming,
    sportid: 4
}]
```

and

```
[{
    personid: 1, 
    name: "john", 
    sportid: 1
},{
    personid: 2,
    name: "mark",
    sportid: 3
},{
    personid: 3,
    name: "steve",
    sportid: 4
},{
    personid: 4,
    name: "marcel",
    sportid: 2
},{
    personid: 5,
    name: "dirk", 
    sportid: 1
},{
    personid: 6, 
    name: "fred", 
    sportid: 2
},{
    personid: 7,
    name: "bart",
    sportid: 3
},{
    personid: 8, 
    name: "lieve",
    sportid: 1
}]
```

output:

```
1 footbal
- john
- dirk
- lieve

2 tennis
- marcel
- fred

3 golf
- mark
- bart

4 swimming
- steve
```

How can `AngularJS` combine the `sport` and `person` that it display on `sport`, sort on `sportid` and each name belongs to the sport via the `sportid`.

*EDIT: I do wanna use `Google Spreadsheet` `json` for multiple useful reasons*

Comment: angular doesn't have a function to combine arrays like this as part of it's library, but it is fully compatible with other javascript libraries that provide this functionality, like underscore.js or lodash

Comment: Thanks @Claies, i will look for those libraries. But in this example (see: plnkr.co/edit/wIiSmRb2c9AzHnTVaId2?p=preview ). I think, it works, but the filter in combination with google spreadsheet failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested elements with ng-repeat, like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="sport in sports ">{{ sport.sport}}
  <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {sportid: sport.sportid}">
    {{ person.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oke thanks, that worked, with inline json but, I do use an external jsondatabase like google spreadsheet, for multiple usefull reasons. As seen here http://plnkr.co/edit/wIiSmRb2c9AzHnTVaId2?p=preview . The repeat in repeat won't work with te filter.

Comment: @Quintenm - that's a different issue altogether.  Your issue there is twofold ...first, you are expecting 2 separate promises to resolve independently but having the data at the same time. It doesn't work that way.  You need to make sure that both promises are resolved before rendering using either promise chaining or $q.all().  Secondly, you're trying to access an object that doesn't exist by using "response.feed.entry" when the actual object is "response.data.feed.entry".  But again, neither of these 2 issues have anything to do with the question you posted.

Comment: thank you. I'm new with the angularjs library and i think after following your tips (promise chaning and $q.all()). I'm a step closer. But still it isn't working, see http://plnkr.co/edit/wIiSmRb2c9AzHnTVaId2 my filter won't work. there are also some console.log outputs if that's help you